Help! Looking for a list of bird-human hybrids in mythology
I'm looking either for a list (linked or in your answer) of half human creatures from any and all mythology that can fly. Specifically, half human half bird. I am aware of harpies and sirens, although they are from Greek mythology. I'm trying to get a list together to use as reference for a book I'm writing without having to spend hours on the Internet looking through obscure mythology websites and Wikipedia (which I know is not an entirely reliable source anyway).
Sorry if this goes against any rules, I'm pretty new to Mythology and Stack Exchange as a whole.

Regarding the rules, list questions tend not to go down too well on SE sites but we do have a few on here.

Garuda, Jatayu, Sampaati as of I know

In Hindu/Buddhist Folk we have 
Garuda
Egyptian Myth: 
Thoth

Came here to mention Thoth, already done though.
